# Handle 27mn records in transformation Pentaho

Tags: pentaho, pentaho-spoon, pentaho-data-integration

I have a list of 45,000 ids. For every id I need to generate the data for every calendar day which at the end will give me 27mn records. I can do it manually by passing the list of ids in the transformation and running it but I wonder what will be the automated way to do it? Save ids in a xls file/txt file in a batch of 1000 records and get Pentaho to read one file, run the transformation, save the output, open another file, run the transformation, save the output etc etc etc?

Comment: Maybe what I should do is to create, let's say 9 files with 5,000 accounts each; save them in csv read them as var (?) in my select; set up the job in such a way that one transformation follows another.

Comment: Hard to understand exactly what you're trying to do here. What I think may be a right approach would be to have a job that contains two transformations. The first transformation reads in the list of IDs (that's it) and then passes that along to the second transformation. The second transformation in the job is configured to "process for every row of input" in the job, and then the transformation contains whatever logic you need for getting the calendar data. Does that help?

Comment: Hi @eicherjc, what I realized is that Pentaho crashes when it comes to proceeding 2mn rows - some transformation requires reading into memory. What I did at the end was to run several jobs each containing four transformations, each handling 2,500 records. With this, only approx 1,500,000 rows were processed during one transformation.